# Check if a value in a dataframe is conditionally between a range of values specified by two columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

So, I have two `dataframes` - somewhat large (df1 ~= 20k rows & df2 ~= 1.5 million) - and I want to check if a value in `df1` is between `df2$low & df2$high`, but do it conditionally (to limit the number of checks) and only do the check if `abs(df1$val-df2$val) < 2`. If the value in df1 is found to be within the df2 range then add into a new column with `TRUE/FALSE` values.

df1

| weight | low | high |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 94.99610 | 94.99608 | 94.99613 |
| 95.00561 | 95.00558 | 95.00566 |

df2

| index | th_weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 94.996092 |
| 2 | 95.496336 |
| 3 | 95.509906 |
| 4 | 97.473292 |
| 5 | 100.519060 |

Desired output should be:

df1

| weight | lower | upper | filter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 94.99610 | 94.99608 | 94.99613 | TRUE |
| 95.00561 | 95.00558 | 95.00566 | FALSE |

So in that example the logic is that rows 4 and 5 in `df2` would get omitted. Value in row 1 of `df2` is within row 1 of `df1$low & df1$high`, therefore `df1[,filter := TRUE]` for that weight

I have tried multiple ways, with double looping into the `data.table`, which, as expected, was the least efficient and I also tried to make a cartesian product of `df1 x df2` with `dplyr::full_join` but having memory issues there. Even splitting into chunks and appending into a  file (so I can later easily manipulate the file via UNIX `sed` or `awk`) didn't help.

There might be a very easy way to do this and I might be completely off-track, so I apologise in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-equi join with `data.table` - convert the first data to data.table (`setDT`), create the `filter` column as logical (`FALSE`) values.  Do a non-equi join, and assign (`:=`) the `filter` to `TRUE`, which changes the `FALSE` to `TRUE` only when the condition (`abs(weight - th_weight) < 2`) meets

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, filter := FALSE]
df1[df2, filter := abs(weight - th_weight) < 2, 
       on = .(low <= th_weight, high >= th_weight)]
```

-output

```
> df1
     weight      low     high filter
      <num>    <num>    <num> <lgcl>
1: 94.99610 94.99608 94.99613   TRUE
2: 95.00561 95.00558 95.00566  FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(weight = c(94.9961, 95.00561), low = c(94.99608, 
95.00558), high = c(94.99613, 95.00566)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(index = 1:5, th_weight = c(94.996092, 95.496336, 
95.509906, 97.473292, 100.51906)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```